# How do I create a typescript project?

Tags: eclipse, node.js, typescript, typecs

I am trying to learn typescript with Node.js and the TypEcs Eclipse plugin. I installed Node.js and did `npm install -g typescript`. I also followed instructions on the [TypEcs](http://typecsdev.com/) front page to install TypEcs with Eclise Luna.

Now I have a typescript perspective as shown below. But there is no project type for TypeScript when I try to create a test project.

[image]

My question is,

How should I start a new TS project with TypEcs?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should install Nodeclipse [Enide Studio 2014](http://www.nodeclipse.org/enide/studio/2014/) plugins for Node.js. Nodeclipse has simple Typescript option in new Node.js project wizards. (It is also better idea to start from simpler JavaScript first)

I am lead of Nodeclipse, I don't yet use Typescript, but I would like to collaborate on the
"Node.js + TypeScript" topic on [GitHub](https://github.com/nodeclipse/nodeclipse-1/). Be ready to share, discuss and research.

Comment: I just a couple days ago created in Eclipse the hello-world-server.ts which fails when I run it with "unexpected token function." I realize this could be due to how I have things set up but I do not know what I am doing wrong. I would also suggest a simple change to the error message where the word "function" is either shown in quotes or italicized, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't got Eclipse here to test, but I believe you can start by creating any of the available project types that includes JavaScript.

If you aren't sure what to use, choose a static web project (this doesn't have any server-side code).